# Firefox doesn't send data when using form.submit()

Tags: javascript, forms

A simple form:

```
<form action="https://httpbin.org/post" method="post">
  <button name="should-be-sent" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And JavaScript which stops the form submission using `preventDefault` and then submits it using `.submit()`.

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  form.submit();
});
```

Here's a fiddle that will show the data that was (or wasn't) sent: https://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/mg86q8mb/

I'd expect the form data to include the `should-be-sent` but in Firefox it doesn't.  Is there a simple way around this problem?

Comment: it seems there is an issue with `.submit()` - _"In general, it is not guaranteed to be invoked by HTML user agents."_ - from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit which links to - http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2012JanMar/0011.html